# Jboss EAP Server Hanged with many waiting threads

Tags: jboss

[image]

Can someone explain me based on the following image.  How to find which objects are in waiting state?

We see the system hangs.. Our system has a External authentication to each page of the portal.. So our system is getting slow and hanged

Threaddump showed the following image..

```
"http-serverIP-8080-107" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000052017000 nid=0x4fa3 in Object.wait() [0x00002ae69d5cf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007145a6148> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await(JIoEndpoint.java:416)
    - locked <0x00000007145a6148> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:442)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: The thread that you shared should not cause you to "hang". It is a proxy thread waiting for a request from apache. It is not really doing anything.

Comment: I just shared the part of log file.. Could you please check the image and see "Threads locking monitors" cause slowness in the portal application

Comment: "http-IPAddress-105" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00000000559aa800 nid=0x4f9b runnable [0x00002ae69d3cd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:700)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.parseRequestLine(InternalInputBuffer.java:366)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:805)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11

Comment: Will the above "RUNNABLE" causes the server issue? -  We see the following statement   indicating the locked                                                                       locked <0x00000007fd22c630> (a java.lang.Object)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:755)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75)
 - locked <0x00000007fd25ae70> (a com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream)

Comment: It's quite difficult to analyze without seeing a few of them taken within an interval (like 8 thread dumps each 10 seconds apart during the time the issue persists). It is beyond scope of this forum to analyze thread dumps. For instance the thread dump may indicate a GC issue then we will have to look at GC logs. I would recommend you contact JBoss support team for help.